# QTabWidget does not react on touch input

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, touch

My Qt 4.8 application runs on a Windows 7 touch screen. I'm not using the QTouchEvent capabilities. In this case and following the documentation, touch events should appear as normal mouse events. Unfortunately, this is not the case for all widgets.

The tabs of QTabWidgets can't be switch by touching them. It works via keyboard inputs. Other widgets work as the should (QPushButton, QLineEdit), interpreting the touch as mouse event.

The widgets are created using the Designer.

Despite the answer might not, my question is simple: 
How can this happen, resp. how to fix this?
Thank's in advance...

Update:

Just figured out that it seems to be a compiler issue. Compiling With msvc2010 SP1 under Windows 8 causes the problem.
Compiling using WinXP and mingw results in a correct behavior.
Unfortunately, I would like to use MS Speech SDK, so I need Win7+ and msvc...

Update 2:
It's getting worse: Using a normal mouse everything reacts as aspected. But touching the screen is ignored. At least on the top half of the screen.
To be even more confusing: Using Qt 4.8 classic widgets does not react (QPushButtin, QLineEdit) but links in a QWebView react. Using Qt 5 it's vice versa.

You can find the application on source forge: httpplayer
http://sourceforge.net/projects/httpplayer/

Comment: It **might** be a Qt4 bug. Or a Windows 7 bug. I have a program, same code, which shows strange and somewhat unpredictable touch behaviour on Windows 7, but perfectly sane behaviour on Windows 8. Perhaps driver? This is pure speculation on my part, but if you have the opportunity, try it on Windows 8.

Comment: Windows always generates mouse messages for touch input, to enable touch input for non-touch-aware applications. If you launch Notepad you will not observe any of the issues you described. The buggy code is further down the processing pipeline, i.e. inside Qt.

Comment: Migrating to the latest Qt version fixed the problem...